# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when I run the program

Tags: c, coredump

(Sorry for my bad English btw)
Well, I'm eve copying the solution of this code. My code is identical to the solution (the code it's ok, it's well done), but when I run the program, it appear a message that says `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I don't know how to show you captures of my program, but my code seems alright.
When I run the program it finishes when it asks for the volume of the Good. Then this message: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` appears

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM 5
#define MAX_WAGON_CAPACITY 0.85
#define MAX_WAGON_CAPACITY_ANIMALS 0.5
#define LIMIT1 500
#define LIMIT2 2500
#define FRAGILE 1.10
#define DANGEROUS 1.15
#define FIRST_PRICE 0.50
#define SECOND_PRICE 0.45
#define THIRD_PRICE 0.40

typedef enum { FOOD, CHEMICAL, ANIMALS, VEHICLES,
               ELECTRONICS, CONSTRUCTION, OTHERS } tGoodType;
typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE } boolean;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int idGood;
    float volumeGood;
    tGoodType typeOfGood;
    boolean isFragile;
    boolean isDangerous;
    float train [NUM];
    int nWagons;
    float volumeTrain;
    float price;  
    float surchargeFragile;
    float surchargeDangerous;

    printf("Good identifier: \n");
    scanf("%d", &idGood);
    printf("\nInsert volume of Good\n");
    scanf("%f", volumeGood);
    printf("\nInsert Good type (0-FOOD, 1-CHEMICAL, 2-ANIMALS, 3-VEHICLES, 4-ELECTRONICS, 5-CONSTRUCTION, 6-OTHERS)\n");
    scanf("%u", &typeOfGood);
    printf("\nIs the Good fragile? (0-FALSE, 1-TRUE)\n");
    scanf("%u", &isFragile);
    printf("\nIs the Good dangerous) (0-FALSE, 1-TRUE\n");
    scanf("%u", &isDangerous);
    printf("\nThe maximum length of the train is>> ");
    scanf("%f", train[0]);
    printf("\nThe length of the locomotive is>> ");
    scanf("%f", train[1]);
    printf("\nThe length of each wagon is>> ");
    scanf("%f", train[2]);
    printf("\nThe space between each wagon is>> ");
    scanf("%f", train[3]);
    printf("\nThe volume of a wagon is>> ");
    scanf("%f", train[4]);

    nWagons = (int)((train[1] - train[2]) / (train[3] + train[4]));

    if (typeOfGood == 2)
        volumeTrain = nWagons * train[4] * MAX_WAGON_CAPACITY_ANIMALS;
    else
        volumeTrain = nWagons * train[4] * MAX_WAGON_CAPACITY;

    price = 0.0;
    surchargeFragile = 0.0;
    surchargeDangerous = 0.0;
    if (volumeTrain >= volumeGood) {
        if (volumeGood > 0 && volumeGood < LIMIT1) { 
            price = volumeGood * FIRST_PRICE;
        } else if (volumeGood >= LIMIT1 && volumeGood <= LIMIT2) {
            price = volumeGood * SECOND_PRICE;
        } else {
            price = volumeGood * THIRD_PRICE;
        }
    }
    if (isFragile == 1) {
        surchargeFragile = (price * FRAGILE) - price;
    }
    if (isDangerous == 1) {
        surchargeDangerous = (price * DANGEROUS) - price;
        price = price + surchargeFragile + surchargeDangerous;
    }   

    if (price > 0.0) {
        printf("The Good id is %d", &idGood);
        printf("The number of wagons is %d", &nWagons);
        printf("The price for the good is %f", &price);
    } else {
        printf("The good does not fit the train");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did your compiler tell you when you tried to compile this? If it didn't give you warnings, enable compiler warnings. If it still doesn't give you warnings, get a better compiler. Fix the warnings, then ask again.

Answer (score 1):

you have several error in your scanf, producing your segmentation fault, they are indicated by the compiler :

> ```
> c.c:38:1: warning: ‘volumeGood’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
> scanf("%f", volumeGood);
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

and

> ```
> c.c:38:9: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
> scanf("%f", volumeGood);
> ```

because the undefined value of *volumeGood* is used as an address where *scanf* will try to write

you probably wanted

```
scanf("%f", &volumeGood);
```

and also all these ones :

> ```
> c.c:46:9: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
> scanf("%f", train[0]);
>         ^
> c.c:48:9: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
> scanf("%f", train[1]);
>         ^
> c.c:50:9: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
> scanf("%f", train[2]);
>        ^
> c.c:52:9: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
> scanf("%f", train[3]);
>         ^
> c.c:54:9: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
> scanf("%f", train[4]);
> ```

because the entries in *train* are used like if they contains addresses, you wanted

```
scanf("%f", &train[0]);
scanf("%f", &train[1]);
scanf("%f", &train[2]);
scanf("%f", &train[3]);
scanf("%f", &train[4]);
```

when you use *scanf* and equivalent you have to give the addresses where the values will be saved

---

Also in

```
c.c:84:29: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("The Good id is %d", &idGood);
                             ^
c.c:85:38: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("The number of wagons is %d", &nWagons);
                                      ^
c.c:86:40: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("The price for the good is %f", &price);
```

that time it is the reverse, you give the address while you have to give the values, must be

```
     printf("The Good id is %d", idGood);
     printf("The number of wagons is %d", nWagons);
     printf("The price for the good is %f", price);
```

Comment: @EOF `gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.c` no warning except about argv argv after the fixes

Comment: Uh, this is embarrassing. I was completely wrong. I should probably go to bed.

Comment: @chqrlie Where is "here"? Anyway, I absolutely need to get off stack overflow when I start to get belligerent while I am totally wrong (because I apparently can't read).